# Worksheet change not working for multiple objects

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to color objects (circles) based on cell value - at the moment just first object is doing an action. What is the issue?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'1'
   If Intersect(Target, Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        If Target.Value < 0.31 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        ElseIf Target.Value >= 0.31 And Target.Value < 0.32999 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        End If
    End If
 '2'
   If Intersect(Target, Range("D6")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        If Target.Value > 0.64 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        ElseIf Target.Value <= 0.64 And Target.Value > 0.65999 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Because you `Exit Sub` if the first is not true.

Comment: If you don't change D5, you have `Exit Sub` which stops any other code working.

Comment: Any reason you don't use Conditional Formatting for that?

Comment: `X <= 1 And X > 2` will never be true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if it is not D5 you `Exit Sub`

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

So it never checks the second because it already exit at the first.

Change it into a construct like this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then 
    ' do stuff 1 
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6")) Is Nothing Then
    ' do stuff 2 
End If
```